Does Ruby have problems with race conditions on local variables when working with threads?
I'm trying to learn more about threads in Ruby
I'm running this code for 10 minutes, and every time I got the same result: index = 480000
    def test
      threads = []
      total_threads = 40000
      index = 0
      total_threads.times do
        threads << Thread.new do
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
          index += 1
        end
      end
      threads.each(&:join)
      puts index
    end

Why this happens? When I work with C and don't use mutexes, this value is often changed, but with Ruby index look's like a atomic variable.
I still have problems no using mutexes with I/O cases, but this simple cases, where I use only local variables inside my programn, I never had a issue with concurrence.
I know that race conditions have a non-deterministic behavior, but what the odds of execute the same code that have a possible race condition for like 300 times, and got the same result every single one?
ps: sometimes I put a 'sleep' between the sums, to assure that more than one thread is acessing the same resource, but the result remains the same

This is because of Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), try running the code in JRuby and you'll see random results. Some reading: Exploring Ruby’s Multi-threaded Weirdness – the examples are quite similar to yours.
